# PHP | Move the Element in Array to New Position

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
[Project 123] => Array
    (
        [2014-12-01] => 13
        [Total] => 373
        [2014-12-02] => 12
        [2014-12-03] => 12
        [2014-12-04] => 12
        [2014-12-05] => 12
        [2014-12-06] => 12
        [2014-12-07] => 12
        [2014-12-08] => 12
        [2014-12-09] => 12
        [2014-12-10] => 12
        [2014-12-11] => 12
        [2014-12-12] => 12
        [2014-12-13] => 12
        [2014-12-14] => 12
        [2014-12-15] => 12
        [2014-12-16] => 12
        [2014-12-17] => 12
        [2014-12-18] => 12
        [2014-12-19] => 12
        [2014-12-20] => 12
        [2014-12-21] => 12
        [2014-12-22] => 12
        [2014-12-23] => 12
        [2014-12-24] => 12
        [2014-12-25] => 12
        [2014-12-26] => 12
        [2014-12-27] => 12
        [2014-12-28] => 12
        [2014-12-29] => 12
        [2014-12-30] => 12
        [2014-12-31] => 12
    )
```

As you can see the array in top. There is a field `373` with the key `Total`,

i want to move it to the end of the array without changing its key `Total` or its value `373`.??
Is it possible to do That.??

Comment: try to use ksort to sort the array based on keys.http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: `unset` it and add once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ksort()` on the parent array:

```
ksort($array['Project 123']);
```

Comment: @SizzlingCode sure man no probl